# random items added to order after purchase?

Tags: orders, error, products, sagepay

I've recently seen this issue where orders are coming through as normal but customers are getting in touch to let us know there is an additional item/(s) in their order confirmation that they did not want. Upon checking, they also haven't paid for this but Magento is showing that everything has been successfully invoiced.

Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: You need to check for custom module. you can test it by disable custom module 1 by 1.

Comment: why suddenly start now though? No new features have been added in months!

Comment: @Danielle have you used any extensions that allow you to 'delete' orders in Magento?

Comment: no Ricky we don't! but your answer below actually enabled me to replicate the issue! I will just play around with the settings and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the ebizmarts sagepay module

Goto system -> configuration -> SagePay -> Advanced Settings

Experiment with these two - 'Verify cart consistency' will fix your issue. If it's set to 'no', a customer can modify their cart in another tab during checkout payment process.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/oONtD6Y.png]

Comment: right so are you suggesting if that setting is set to "no" then I try to checkout as normal but open another tab and then add something else to my basket that I could carry on as normal in the original tab and pay for just one item but the order would contain both tabs worth? Interesting if that's the case! I wouldn't think that would be possible

Comment: @Danielle it's definately possible, I've seen questions similar to yours pop up on here in the past. The issue is that the setting is 'no' by default, to be honest. I've also experienced your issue in the past by having an extension that allowed orders to be 'deleted' causing random stuff to get added from old quotes.